# Launching GUI app (Firefox) when VS Code development inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to dockerize a python project that uses selenium with Firefox (GUI version, not headless). The goal is to provide a fully dockerized development environment inside of which one would develop as well using [VS Code support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for development inside of Docker containers. I am using `ubuntu:18.04` image on Ubuntu 18.04 host.

I have exported the display variable using `dockerfile.json`:

```
"containerEnv": {
    "DISPLAY": "${localEnv:DISPLAY}"
}
```

Yet, I am still getting the following error when starting `firefox` from the bash inside of my container:

```
root@af414fe6783f:/workspaces/my_project# firefox

(firefox:242): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:59:09.711: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

calling `env` from inside of the console results in:

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Running Desktop Apps in Docker](https://medium.com/better-programming/running-desktop-apps-in-docker-43a70a5265c4)
 apart from setting the display variable (different depending on the host OS) one needs to enable access to the X Server (`xhosts +` in Linux/Ubuntu). My setup was missing that permission `xhosts +` and it works now.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same goal. Python based selenium tests in devcontainer. But I'm still struggeling. Do you have any references which explain what you did?

Comment: yes, just click on the link above in my answer